# Why await is not taken in consideration after deploy?

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloudbees

I have a method which does some sync calls to a specific REST api, something like:

```
WSRequestHolder url = WS.url("rest_api_url");
Promise<WS.Response> promisePerPage = url.get();
promisePerPage.getWrappedPromise().await(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
WS.Response responsePerPage = promisePerPage.get();
ProductsWrapper productsWrapper = new Gson().fromJson(responsePerPage.getBody(), ProductsWrapper.class);
```

As you notice, I put 3 seconds between calls so each request can be parsed in time and inserted in DB. All works great locally but after I deploy to cloud, all goes continuously, without any more waiting (3 seconds) between requests...

Do you know why?

Comment: Maybe there is more than one Thread for serving the requests in prod configuration ?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose this even that I don't see any setting in application.conf but maybe it's a setting on clodubees... and in this case how can I solve my issue...?

Comment: But I don't get why you need these 3 seconds ?

Comment: @nico_ekito I am doing some external REST requests and have a limit per minutes...so I put a small pause between requests.

Comment: Try using some kind of "queue" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use play's async features.

I have a test up at http://play2-on-cb-features-test.hadashi.cloudbees.net/java/async-test which returns something after 3 seconds.

I have put up some sample code at https://github.com/CloudBees-community/play2-on-cb-features-test/blob/master/app/controllers/JavaTest.java#L13

Play doesn't run many request threads, so it out requests that are too long. I guess there are probably different settings for production. You can modify this behaviour in the Akka configuration, but it is better just to use the Async support in play.

For more documentation on Async in play read http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaAsync